# Pagination like Flickr

Tags: php, arrays, pagination

I recently ran into a problem with my pagination, it happens that there are like a 100 pages, so obviously my pagination becomes way to long.

Now I want to prevent this by removing some links, so instead of

```
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9 - 10
```

I want to show it as

```
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - ... - 10
```

Or when you're on page 4

```
1 - ... - 4 - 5 - 6 - ... 10
```

At the moment the script that displays my pagination goes like this:

```
$links = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $totalPages; $i++) {
    array_push($links, $i);
    }

foreach($links as $pageLink) {
    if($pageLink == $page) {
    $pagination .= "<li><a href='" . BASE_URL . $url . $pageLink . ".html' class='active'>" . ($pageLink + 1) . "</a></li>";
    } else {
        if($pageLink === '...') {
            $pagination .= "<li><a href='#'>...</a></li>";
        } else {
            $pagination .= "<li><a href='" . BASE_URL . $url . $pageLink . ".html'>" . ($pageLink + 1) . "</a></li>";
        }
    }   
}
```

I added all the links in an array so it would be easy to adjust this, but I can't figure out how I can get the pagination like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow you can get the current page number and the last page number. The pager item which represents your current page should be somewhat different from your other pages. If your page number is smaller or equal than 3 you show 1 2 3 ... LastPageNumber and if your current page is greater or equal than LastPageNumber - 2  then your paging should look like 1 ... 67 68 69. Otherwise your paging should look like 1 ... 30 31 32 33 34 ... 69 (in this example your current page is 32).

Comment: Thanks, I only can't figure out how to do the middle part, this is what I got now: http://pastebin.com/3m3z9aBa, it returns the correct links for the first and last pages, but not sure how to go on with the middle ones

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out: http://pastebin.com/pHQJRzYN
Thanks a lot for the help, just couldn't get around the thinking to get there.